# Google Earth plugin time slider stays running

Tags: google-earth-plugin

Google Earth plugin time slider stays running even though the kmz file ends. Time seems to run forever even not stopped manually. See the the page
http://www.sodanjaljet.fi/kuhmo/

Some other page has basically the same code code, but does not stay running, it ends as the kmz file is finished, see the page
http://www.sodanjaljet.fi/uncategorized/viipurinlahti-helmi-maaliskuussa-1940/

The problem code below

```
 <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var ge;
  var firsttime = 0;
  var timer;
  google.load("earth", "1", {"other_params":"sensor=false"});

  function init() 
  {
     google.earth.createInstance('map3d', initCB, failureCB);
  }

  function initCB(instance) 
  {
     var defaultRate = 1; // 1 second in the plugin for each real second.
     var speedyRate = 60*60*24*4; // 1 day for each real second.        
     ge = instance;
     ge.getWindow().setVisibility(true);        
     addSampleButton('Alkuun', camera);
     ge.getNavigationControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_SHOW);
     var href = 'http://www.sodanjaljet.fi/wp-content/uploads/kmz/Kuhmo2.kmz';
     google.earth.fetchKml(ge, href, function(kmlObject) {
           if (kmlObject)
              ge.getFeatures().appendChild(kmlObject);
           if (kmlObject.getAbstractView() !== null)
              ge.getView().setAbstractView(kmlObject.getAbstractView());
     });   
     ge.getTime().getControl().setVisibility(ge.VISIBILITY_SHOW); 
  }

  function failureCB(errorCode) 
  {
  }

  function camera() 
  {
    var lookAt = ge.getView().copyAsLookAt(ge.ALTITUDE_RELATIVE_TO_GROUND);
    lookAt.setLatitude(63.95335);
    lookAt.setLongitude(30.08484);
    lookAt.setRange(20000.0); //default is 0.0
    lookAt.setTilt(30);
    lookAt.setHeading(0);
    ge.getView().setAbstractView(lookAt);  
    start();  
  }


  function setRate(rate)
  {
    var rate = 60*60*24*4;
    var extents = ge.getTime().getControl().getExtents();      
    if (firsttime == 0)
        start();
    firsttime = 1;
    ge.getTime().setRate(eval(rate));
  }

  function setRate2(rate)
  {
    var rate = 60*60*24*4;
    var time = ge.getTime().getTimePrimitive();
    ge.getTime().setRate(eval(0));
  }

  function addSampleButton(caption, clickHandler) 
  {
    var btn = document.createElement('input');
    btn.type = 'button';
    btn.value = caption;
    if (btn.attachEvent)
        btn.attachEvent('onclick', clickHandler);
    else
        btn.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
    document.getElementById('sample-ui').appendChild(btn);
  }


  function start() 
  {
    var groundOverlay = ge.createGroundOverlay('');
    var timeSpan = ge.createTimeSpan('');
    timeSpan.getBegin().set('1940-01-01');
    timeSpan.getEnd().set('1940-01-03');
    groundOverlay.setTimePrimitive(timeSpan)
    ge.getFeatures().appendChild(groundOverlay);
    ge.getTime().setTimePrimitive(timeSpan);
  }

  google.setOnLoadCallback(init);

  </script>
```

The code works other way fine, there are play, stop, and "back to begin" buttons, and they work. Time not stopping is however quite an annoying problem. 
Any ideas how to get it stop?

Thanks in advance.
br
jouko